# Difference of behaviour when clicking an "indeterminate" checkbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, checked

**UPDATE:** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099158/how-to-deal-with-browser-differences-with-indeterminate-checkbox).
The linked Q has no proper answers, without even letting me the time to find one and post it here. So if you are interested in the answer, check the one I posted in the "duplicate" question https://stackoverflow.com/a/19447939/1010492.

---

I am trying to display a checkbox with the "indeterminate" state, which becomes checked when you click it.

To do so, I am initialising the checkbox in JavaScript this way:

```
checkbox.checked = false;
checkbox.indeterminate = true;
```

On Chrome and Firefox, the checkbox will become checked after clicking it (this is the desired behaviour). On Internet Explorer, it will become un-checked.

However, if I initialise the checkbox to `checked = true`, the exact opposite behaviour can be observed.

I am struggling to find a solution to initialise the checkbox to the right value so it behaves as desired.
I have not been able to find a satisfying solution on stackoverflow. **I do not want to use an image solution (I want the native browser's look and behaviour), and I am not too keen neither on messing with mousedown and click events...**

What's the best approach you can suggest? I'm not too keen on using user agent detection since IE11 is coming soon, but is there really a choice?

Comment: tried using jquery? That may help

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal jQuery *is* JavaScript!

Comment: yes and that takes care of most of your cross browser statements that you may need

Comment: The answer of the "possible duplicate" is to use an image... Not helpful. My requirement is to keep the native look & behaviour of the images. I'd rather use user agent detection than this.
@ComFreek: thank you my friend, people seem to be forgetting that :)

Comment: @GyumFox Here is a solution which works in IE 11 and Chrome 31 for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fnf5A/1/ Besides voting for reopening your question, I also removed the offensive part of your edited question.

Comment: @ComFreek Thanks for giving it a try. It does not work on IE10, the checkbox become uncheck (guess they've changed the behaviour on IE11...). I'm happy enough with the feature-detection technique I proposed in the "duplicate" question, it also has the benefit not to interfere with the normal browser behaviour.