# IE does not fire 'Change' event on indeterminate checkbox when you click on it

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, checkbox

i have a tri-state checkbox and i need the change event to be fired when the user clicks on it but the IE won't fire it when the checkbox's state is on "INDETERMINATE" (browser bug maybe?).
As work around for IE i could trigger the change event programmatically but this doesn't work for my case because i need to know if the event was fired because the user actually clicked on it.

[Fiddle here / Test on IE and Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/K6nrT/26/)

```
<label for="cb">
  <input id="cb" type="checkbox" />
   click me
</label>

var checkbox = document.getElementById("cb");
checkbox.indeterminate = true;
$('#cb').change(function(){alert('Change Event')});
```

I have read this article https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1698 and [How to deal with browser differences with indeterminate checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099158/how-to-deal-with-browser-differences-with-indeterminate-checkbox) but i could find a specific resolution for my case.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1698

Comment: I have already read that and won't work for my case

Comment: Ya, just tested it, doesn't work

Comment: It looks like it would work but that's an ugly fix  (it handles space key too): http://jsfiddle.net/5ro92490/

Comment: Yep the thing is that i need e.originalEvent not to be undefined http://jsfiddle.net/5ro92490/1/ if you test it on crhome works fine

Comment: Not sure what is your expected behaviour but you could dispatch event instead: http://jsfiddle.net/5ro92490/2/  See if that fit your needs

Comment: ok that might work, will try a workaround thank you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checkbox inputs can only have two states: checked or unchecked. The indeterminate state is visual only and it masks the real state of the checkbox.

The first time you click on a checkbox that has its indeterminate set to `true` will simply change it to `false` and the checkbox will show its real state. For that reason, the change from "indeterminate" to either "checked" or "unchecked" is not a change in the real state and it does not trigger the `onchange` event.

Interestingly, the only browser that implements this behaviour correctly is IE. You can test this in IE and other browsers:

```js
document.getElementById("cb1").indeterminate = true;
document.getElementById("cb2").indeterminate = true;
```

```html
<label for="cb1"><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />I'm actually checked</label>
<label for="cb2"><input id="cb2" type="checkbox" />I'm actually unchecked</label>
```

In IE, the first click will reveal the real state of the checkbox. In Chrome, it will change the real state to the other real state.

Although IE implementation is the correct one technically, the implementation of the other browsers is the more practical one. For most applications, the visual "indeterminate" state needs to be considered as a real state just like the "checked" and "unchecked" which means that the change from any of those 3 states to another one should trigger the `onchange` event.

How to solve this? Well, the most obvious answer can be to register a one-time click event for IE only, like the one suggested by https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1698.

```
// As other browsers already fire the change event,
// only bind the listener for IE.
if ( window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident') >= 0 ) {
    $(function(){
        // Pointer events in IE10, IE11 can be handled as mousedown.
        $(document).on('mousedown', 'input', function(){
            // Only fire the change event if the input is indeterminate.
            if ( this.indeterminate ) {
                $(this).trigger('change');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

However, the more generic approach given by [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) is probably a better approach as it is always better to avoid browser-specific code whenever possible:

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("cb");
checkbox.indeterminate = true;
$('#cb').one('click', function () {
    if (!this.checked) {
        this.checked = true;
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}).change(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert(e.originalEvent)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cb">
    <input id="cb" type="checkbox" />click me
</label>
```

Comment: To be clear about the correct behaviour, the specs say https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox), which says clicking on an indeterminate checkbox should toggle the value. IE however, just removes the indeterminate state.

Comment: @ClarkPan Yes, the specs in that document are confusing. It clearly stats that the indeterminate attribute *has no effect except for changing the appearance of checkbox controls.* which means that the IE behaviour is the correct one. But then it says *The pre-click activation steps consist of setting the element's checkedness to its opposite value* which contradicts the first statement assuming that the pre-click activation means clicking on checkbox that has its indeterminate set to false.

Comment: thats one way to interpret it and it seems to be the way the IE team has. The way I interpret it is that, irregardless of the indeterminate attribute, clicking on the checkbox will toggle the checked state. In this scenario, the correct behaviour of clicking an indeterminate checkbox would be to remove the indeterminate flag, then change checked to be opposite of its current value. This is what the other browsers do. IE, only sets the indeterminate state to be false, but doesn't toggle the underlying checked state. This is the reason it doesn't fire the change event.

Comment: @ClarkPan Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say in my answer. It's really annoying to have such vague specs that are open to different interpretations. The only reason to have standards is so everybody implements the specs in the exact same way. Having vague standards/specs brings us to square one where it's implemented differently, rendering the standards/specs pretty much pointless.

Comment: Note, that the realistic case would likely involve fixing this issue for labels linked with checkboxes, keydown, and touchstart events.